# Spring AOP - the Json I'm sending is not received in JointPoint

Tags: aop, spring-aop

I'm new to this AOP technique and is having problems with getting the json body inside the methods in Aspect class.

Here is my controller method:

```java
@PostMapping("/startDMS")   
@ResponseBody 
public String getDmsInitialisePageValidToken(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody JSONObject requestJson) {
   logger.debug("/initialiseView");
   return "{\"SUCCESS\" :\"DMS initialisation.\"}";
}
```

And here is my aspect methods:

```java
@Around("tokenValidationPointCut()")
public Object validateToken(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    try {

        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        Object[] requestParams = pjp.getArgs();
        System.out.println("Array Object Length: " + requestParams.length);
        if (requestParams != null && requestParams.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("Object2: " + requestParams[1]);
            for (Object object : requestParams) {
                if (JSONObject.class.equals(object.getClass())) {
                    requestJson = (JSONObject) object;
                    System.out.println("Json Object: " + requestJson);
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }
        //rest of the code

        if(Constants.TOKEN_VALIDATION_STATUS.TOKEN_VALIDATION_SUCCESS.equals(jsonTknObject.getTokenValidation().getStatus())) {

            return pjp.proceed();
        }

    }catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return loginViews.getTokenValidationError(request);
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.dms.controller.*.*ValidToken(..))")
public void tokenValidationPointCut() {
    System.out.println("This method is tokenValidationPointCut.");
}
```

I'm using Postman to do the testing, and I send the Json as body. But in the code, where I'm printing the received json, the output is like this:

```
20:20:52,570 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Array Object Length: 2
20:20:52,570 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Object2: {}
20:20:52,570 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Json Object: {}
```

Here is the json string:

```
{
    "JSON_INITIATE": {
    "initialisation": {
    "status": "REQUEST",
    "token": "abcd1234",
    "user_id": "1234",
    "user_role":"GA",
    "request_type":"DMS_INITIALISATION"
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution for this issue. Instead of receiving the object as JSONObject, I tried with String and it works fine.

```
public String getDmsInitialisePageValidToken(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String requestJson) {
   //code here
}
```

Only problem is I have to write an additional line of code to convert the String to JSONObject.

Still wondering why the first method with JSONObject didn't work!

Comment: So the problem was not AOP-related? It also occurred without the aspect because of the `JSONObject` parameter? Please confirm. If however the JSON object works when the aspect is inactive, please let me know. I am an AOP expert, but not a Spring user. If there is an aspect problem, I still can help. You did not really describe what was going wrong in the first place.